# Htaccess redirection - www to non www + add trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Edit: I forgot to mention each folder has one index.php and no .htaccess file. The blog folder has more folders within it, but I don't think that affects anything.

the problem is my php site handles www and non trailing slashes incorrectly. I am trying to redirect all www to non www and make trailing slashes required. What's weird is I have no .htaccess anywhere on my server and each innerpage is responding differently. For example, this is one that append the foldername to the entire URL:

Correct destination: minecraftium/blog/

```
minecraftium.com/blog --> www.minecraftium.comblog
www.minecraftium.com/blog --> www.minecraftium.comblog
www.minecraftium.como/blog/ --> www.minecraftium.comblog
```

This one below didn't do any appending and added the trailing slash, but doesn't redirect www to non www:

Correct destination: minecraftium.com/play-minecraft-sp/

```
minecraftium.com/play-minecraft-sp --> minecraftium.com/play-minecraft-sp/
www.minecraftium.com/play-minecraft-sp --> www.minecraftium.com/play-minecraft-sp/
```

I'm wondering why they are redirecting differently, but I'm more interested in the .htaccess code required to make all www to non www and require trailing slashes. I just moved from Wordpress so I don't know much about .htaccess. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your current .htaccess content? Do you have .htaccess in other folders?

Comment: I have nothing in my .htaccess file and I don't have .htaccess in any other folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root (where `http://www.minecraftium.com/` would go to):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed.